# Display Updated Date Instead of Published Date

Tags: posts, post-meta, date

Both published and updated date are showing on the post page. How can I replace the published date if the last date is updated?

The code is here:

```
Published on <a class="entry-date" href="<?php echo 
get_month_link(get_post_time('Y'),get_post_time('m')); ?>" > 
<span itemprop="datePublished"><?php echo get_the_date('M j, Y'); ?> 
</span>/a>  
<span class="entry-meta" itemprop="dateModified"><font color="ea2f10">Last 
updated on: <?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php 
the_modified_date('g:i a'); ?></font></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
Published on <a class="entry-date" href="<?php echo 
get_month_link(get_post_time('Y'),get_post_time('m')); ?>" > 
<span itemprop="datePublished"><?php echo the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?> 
</span></a>
```

This will replace the published date by the last modified